# can not run npx react-native init MyApp

Tags: node.js, react-native, installation

`$ npx react-native init BMO --version 0.65
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wifgl.png)

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

```
           ######                ######
         ###     ####        ####     ###
        ##          ###    ###          ##
        ##             ####             ##
        ##             ####             ##
        ##           ##    ##           ##
        ##         ###      ###         ##
         ##  ########################  ##
      ######    ###            ###    ######
  ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###
```

#### ## ###      ####      ### ##

### ####      ########      ####

### ###     ##########     ###

### ####      ########      ####

#### ## ###      ####      ### ##

```
  ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###
      ######    ###            ###    ######
         ##  ########################  ##
        ##         ###      ###         ##
        ##           ##    ##           ##
        ##             ####             ##
        ##             ####             ##
        ##          ###    ###          ##
         ###     ####        ####     ###
           ######                ######


              Welcome to React Native!
             Learn once, write anywhere
```

✖ Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN     react-native@"0.69.0" from the root project
npm WARN     1 more (@react-native-community/cli)
npm WARN   1 more (use-sync-external-store)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-shallow-renderer
npm WARN   react-shallow-renderer@"16.14.1" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-shallow-renderer
npm WARN     react-shallow-renderer@"16.14.1" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/update-browserslist-db/-/update-browserslist-db-1.0.4.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'update-browserslist-db@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/update-browserslist-db/-/update-browserslist-db-1.0.4.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-24T10_28_55_204Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `npx reac-native`, it should be `npx react-native`.

Comment: I type npx npx react-native init Myapp

Comment: on my screen show npx react-native init BMO
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-nativ

Comment: npm WARN     react-native@"0.69.0" from the root project
npm WARN     1 more (@react-native-community/cli)
npm WARN   1 more (use-sync-external-store)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1

Comment: npm WARN   node_modules/react-shallow-renderer
npm WARN     react-shallow-renderer@"16.14.1" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated